# Тире после перечисления.

Tags: пунктуация

Катер двухместный, прогулочный, такой давали за победу в конкурсе.
Нужно ли здесь тире перед "такой"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считаю, что тире вполне уместно, т.к. слово "такой" выполняет здесь функцию обобщающего слова.